# Ko Mapping doing Append instead of just reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

When i try to get some array from server and push to an array i do

```
   myarray.push(item[i]); //myarray is ko.observableArray()
```

but i wanted to use  ko.mapping.fromJS, but it always seems to reload the `ko.observableArray()` instead of appending on existing array when i try to add new set of data.

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, myarray);
```

**How can i get it to append when i go pull new set of array?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the key option for the mapping literal, otherwise mapping cant determin which rows are which in the data and in the viewmdodel

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#highlighter_841596

Comment: I was going to suggest this too, but couldn't figure out how to make the `mapping` plugin to append new items, not update existing ones. Is this even possible?

Comment: Append new works out of the box once key option is implemented. However all items must be presented in the data object, otherwise the missing items will be removed from the ViewModel

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about - without all items present in the new array it doesn't matter whether you use `mapping` key or not - items would be lost...

Comment: but the question is about appending. He hasnt specified if the data wont contain all entire dataset or not.. Here is  a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1n4bd2qb/

Comment: think of it like a paged datasets. i pull row 1 to 25 first using ajax from server. and pull next 25 every time user wants to see more. so server only send 25 items on each request not all.

Comment: It wont support that, you will have to map it seperate and then append the lines to your array

Answer (score 0):

You could have done it like this

```
var temp = ko.mapping.toJS(myarray())
var result = temp.concat(result)
ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, myarray);
```